# How to bring NuGet packages into SVN?

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, visualsvn

I use Visual Studio 2012 with VisualSVN plugin, which I believe the best in handling source control with SVN.

I found that it won't add or commit NuGet packages unless I do it manually with TortoiseSVN.

I thought that adding the `packages` directory recursively to solution helps because VisualSVN will detect the files and add them to Subversion.

Any idea on how to synchronize SVN repository with NuGet packages downloaded for the solution?

Comment: It's *not common* to add Nuget packages to version-control. Why don't you use "Nuget Package Restore" option? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769359/761095

Comment: +1 because I didn't know of it. But it was already selected, and when downloading from SVN compilation did fail for missing references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nuget packages must be stored in own repository (if publishing of packages for team is needed), not in Subversion repo - you haven't any reasons for *versioning artifacts*